# Problem to process visually identical looking characters (umlauts)

Tags: python, character-encoding, utf

This may probably be a more general issue related to character encoding, but since I came across the issue while coding an outer join of two dataframes, I post it with a Python code example.

**On the bottom line the question is: why is `ö` technically not the identical character as `ö` and how can I make sure, both are not only visually identical but also technically?
If you copy-paste both characters in a text editor and do a search for one of them, you will never find both!**

So now the Python example trying to do a simple outer join of two dataframes on the column 'filename' (here presented as CSV data):

df1:

```
filename;abstract
problematic_ö.txt;abc
non-problematic_ö.txt;yxz
```

df2:

```
bytes;filename
374;problematic_ö.txt
128;non-problematic_ö.txt
```

Python code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv', header=0, sep = ';')
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv', header=0, sep = ';')

print(df1) 
print(df2) 

df_outerjoin = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', indicator=True)
df_outerjoin.to_csv('df_outerjoin.csv', sep =';', index=False, header=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

print(df_outerjoin)
```

Output:

```
#               filename   abstract     bytes        _merge
1      problematic_ö.txt        abc       NaN     left_only
2  non-problematic_ö.txt        yxz     128.0          both
3      problematic_ö.txt        NaN     374.0    right_only
```

So the 'ö' in the problematic filename isn't recognised as the same character as 'ö' in the non-problematic filename.

What is happening here?

What can I do to overcome this issue — can I do something "smart" by importing the data files with special encoding setting or will I have to do a dumb search and replace?

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways to represent the same character in Unicode. In your situation, the problematic filename contains the character 'ö', which is really represented by two Unicode code points: 'o' (Latin Small Letter O) and the combining character ''. (Combining Diaeresis) The non-problematic filename, on the other hand, uses the character 'ö' (Latin Small Letter O with Diaeresis), which is represented by a single Unicode code char.

You can use `unicodedata` library - `unicodedata.normalize`.

It works like this

```
import unicodedata

a = "ö"
b = "ö"
print(a == b)

a = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', a)
b = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', b)

print(a == b)
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using `unicodedata`, Pandas provides the following method `Series.str.normalize(form)`, so something like:

```py
df1['filename'] = df1['filename'].str.normalize('NFC')
df2['filename'] = df2['filename'].str.normalize('NFC')
```

Before doing the outer join.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that characters with diacritics can often be represented either with so-called **combining diacritics** or as so-called **precomposed characters** in Unicode. The first instance in `problematic_ö.txt` is `U+006F U+0308` (o with a combining di(a)eresis diacritic), while the second instance in `non-problematic_ö.txt` is the precomposed `U+00F6`.

To normalize, try this:

```python
import unicodedata

oUml_combDiac = '\u006F\u0308' # 'ö' (combining diacritic)
oUml_precomp = '\u00F6' # 'ö' (precomposed)
oUml_combDiac == oUml_precomp
# False
unicodedata.normalize('NFC', oUml_combDiac) == \
  unicodedata.normalize('NFC', oUml_precomp)
# True
```

(`oUml` here stands for "o with umlaut".)